# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Umbraco

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco

Hi I have a umbraco site setup at the moment. It is the latest version of umbraco.

Umbraco does not support mvc 5 as of yet. I am trying to setup an admin area for the site. I want the admin area to use the default setting you get with a new mvc site as in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.

Alot of the class that Microsoft.AspNet.Identity dont seem to work well within the umbraco site. I.e. I have assembly that are reliant on different versions of assembly that are already in the umbraco solution.

I looked at creating a virtual application for another mvc site within the umbraco site. This was failing based on

Could not load file or assembly 'umbraco' or one of its dependencies. When this reference is added other errors occur.

I am best trying to add the functunality login area in the umbraco.web.ui solution itself, a virtual application directory with a new mvc site or another approach. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up in dependency hell trying to get this working in v6.2.4 but you should be ok in the latest v7 if you want to try this https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity. It's a project started by one of the lead developers on the Umbraco Core team.

Simon

Comment: Hi I got it working with the default asp.net identity provider in the end. Was painful but got there.

Comment: @user1853454 could you share how did you achieve that?